# iOS puts a required height constraint on custom keyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextfield, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard for a `UITextField`. This is not a system extension; it's within my app only.

```
myTextField.inputView = CustomKeyboard()
```

The `CustomKeyboard` class has subviews and auto layout constraints that require a bit more height than the usual system keyboard. This causes an error because the system is adding a required `customKeyboard.height == 216` constraint.

How do I tell it not to add this constraint? It's added to the array of constraints in the `CustomKeyboard`'s `superview`.

```
(lldb) po type(of: self)
MyApp.CustomKeyboard    
(lldb) po self.superview!.constraints[0]
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428ab40 MyApp.CustomKeyboard:0x100d37580.height == 216   (active)>
```

Comment: The input view height is imposed by the system. You should not be trying to subvert it. You need your constraints to work _with_ this, not against it.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I ask because I see statements in other places that make it sound like some people got more height from a custom keyboard. (Maybe previous iOS versions?)

Comment: With a _custom_ keyboard. But this is just an input view.

Comment: I guess a related question then is: can one make a custom keyboard and keep it private to their app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got an answer from Apple developer support. I've implemented this and it works. Here's what they said:

> If your `inputView` is using Auto Layout and has enough constraints such that it can determine its own height (which is the case in your example project), then all you need to do is override `intrinsicContentSize` in your input view and return a `CGSize` with a height that is *not* `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`.  For example, this will do:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: 0)
}
```

Comment: Just a note of caution when the height is `0` when dismissing the keyboard it doesn't animate the keyboard coming down. Better set to it a computed height

Comment: How do you write it in modern swift?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you did not show your CustomKeyboard code. But in all probability the issue here is that it is not a UIInputView subclass. Make it a UIInputView subclass and now you can set its frame; the origin and width will be ignored, but the height will be obeyed. Make sure that your UIInputView's internal constraints do not conflict with this height.

Comment: I tried a few things. Setting the frame or making the base class UIInputView had no effect at first. Then I stopped setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on my CustomKeyboard view, and passing a frame to init now has some effect. Do you think this should work with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false`? That's what I always do with programmatically created views, since I like to use auto layout.  This seems bizarre. I may use one of my Apple tech support tickets here.